# Databricks SQL equivalent to "Create Trigger" logic?

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a Databricks SQL equivalent to "Create Trigger" logic? Basically every time table X gets new data, a few merge statements need to run on another table.

Alternatively, can a notebook be triggered whenever table X updates?

Even more alternatively, what about monitoring table X with some other Azure service/ADF and triggering required SQL statements?

Desired result is to be able to update a table Y upon updates in table X without this blocking some other activity, so if the solution is code based, it should not block the execution of the rest of the code in a notebook, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your data in [Delta Format](https://databricks.com/product/delta-lake-on-databricks),  you have access to a [Change Data Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-change-data-feed).

If the data changes are new files appearing in your data lake, you can also use [Autoloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader) to create a [Streaming job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/getting-started/spark/streaming) that is triggered for each new file.

Comment: Thanks David, monitoring the change data feed allows me to trigger the immediate update actions from within Databricks by combining PySpark and SQL.